# Using AVERAGE with ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'd like to use the ARRAYFORMULA version of this equation:

`=IFERROR(((AVERAGE(SPLIT(C3, CHAR(10)))) + (AVERAGE(SPLIT(D3, CHAR(10)))) + (AVERAGE(SPLIT(E3, CHAR(10))))) / 3)`

From the reading I have done, it seems AVERAGE does not work well with ARRAYFORMULA?

Here is a quick image of inputs and expected outputs working fine with the formula above being dragged down in column F. But I'd like to do this with ARRAYFORMULA instead. Or perhaps BYROW solution as I'd like to get a better understanding of how to use it.

[image: input/output example]

Appreciate any help I can get.

**EDIT**

Could I also be provided with the option to display the average in this way instead?

[image: output design option 2]

Answer (score 2):

`MAP()` function can work in your case. Try-

```
=MAP(C1:C2,D1:D2,E1:E2,
LAMBDA(x,y,z,AVERAGE(
AVERAGE(SPLIT(x,CHAR(10))),
AVERAGE(SPLIT(y,CHAR(10))),
AVERAGE(SPLIT(z,CHAR(10)))
)))
```

To refer full columns as input ranges, use-

```
=MAP(
C1:INDEX(C1:C,COUNTA(C1:C)),
D1:INDEX(D1:D,COUNTA(C1:C)),
E1:INDEX(E1:E,COUNTA(C1:C)),
LAMBDA(x,y,z,AVERAGE(
AVERAGE(SPLIT(x,CHAR(10))),
AVERAGE(SPLIT(y,CHAR(10))),
AVERAGE(SPLIT(z,CHAR(10)))
)))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, could you break this formula down for me please? Thanks!

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Yep!

I am using named ranges instead, but it looks like it doesn't mind them.

Comment: I have also edited my question to include a variation of the average output that I would like to explore. If you could help out with it, that would be awesome, thank you.